# Sets with spheres in open intervals, measure theory

Tags: measure-theory

Extract from a proof in a measure theory script:

---

For each set $A \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ and each $r>0$, we set.
$$
A_{r}:=\{x \in A: B(x, r) \subseteq A\}
$$
Let $\Sigma$ be an algebra in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ containing all open subsets of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, then for any set $A \in \Sigma$ and any $r>0$, we have $A_{r} \in \Sigma$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $d$ be the Euclidean metric on $\mathbb{R}^n$. It is not hard to verify that
$$A_r = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n : d(x, A^c) \geq r\}.$$
Since the map $f \colon \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x) = d(x, A^c)$ is continuous and $A_r = f^{-1}([r, \infty))$, it follows that $A_r$ is closed. Since your algebra contains all open sets, it contains all complements of open sets, i.e. all closed sets.

Comment: Thanks for your adive. What do you think about my attempt?

Comment: It looks good. It is essentially the same as my proof.

Answer (score 0):

My attempt to prove this statement:
Let $U$ be the union of all balls $B_r(x)$ with $x\in A^c.$ Then $A_r=A\setminus U.$
It follows
$$
x \in U \Leftrightarrow \exists y \in A^c : x\in B_r(y)\\
$$
$$
\Leftrightarrow \exists y \in A^c : y\in B_r(x)
$$
$$
\Leftrightarrow B_r(x)\not\subset A
$$
It follows that $$x\in A\setminus U \Leftrightarrow x \in A \land B_r(x)\subset A \Leftrightarrow x \in A_r.$$
And thus $A_r=A \setminus U \in \Sigma.$
We know that $U\in \Sigma$ since $U$  is a union of open sets. $\quad \blacksquare$